# Why is this code causing typescript to treat a type as a value?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, higher-order-functions

Say, for the sake of argument, I want to make a higher order function that lets me easily create a simple narrowing function. So I write:

```
function createNarrow<T>(): (n: unknown) => n is T {
  return (n: unknown): n is T => n instanceof T;
}
                                              ^
Error: 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. ts(2693)
```

For some reason, typescript thinks my type, which is clearly being passed in as a type, is a value and not a type. Why is this happening?

Comment: Because `instanceof` is a runtime operator that only acts on values, not types, which are [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-from-scratch.html#erased-types) upon compilation to JS.  By writing `n instanceof T` you are using `T` as a value, which is essentially nonsense... at runtime your code will look like  `function createNarrow() { return (n) => n instanceof T; }`... what's `T`?   Does that fully address your question?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?